# How can I extract words from a file from a string

Tags: python

So I have tried to make it so that I can extract words in a file with every English word from random letters a generator gives me. Then I would like to add the found words to a list. But I am having a bit of a problem acquiring this result. Could you help me please?

This is what I have tried:

```
import string
import random

def gen():
  b = []
  for i in range(100):
    a = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    b.append(a)
    
    
    with open('allEnglishWords.txt') as f:
      words = f.read().splitlines()
      joined = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in b])
      if joined in words:
        print(joined)
      f.close()
  
  print(joined)

gen()
```

if you are wondering where I got the txt file it is located here http://www.gwicks.net/dictionaries.htm. I downloaded the one labeled **ENGLISH - 84,000 words** the text file

Comment: What does _"extract words from a file with every English word from random letters"_ mean? Your `joined` is just a string of random letters increasing on each `for` iteration. At some point your `if` is doing something like this: `if 'rtvdnetohtrbcrvkpbfd' in ['good', 'bad', 'ugly', ...]`.

Comment: Also, you're opening and closing the file for every iteration. You should read that file only once and store the words in a variable to be used after anywhere else.

Comment: that could quite possibly be my problem @NiltonMoura, but the thing is I don't really know any other way of doing it. (also I am a bit new to the with open command)

Comment: You haven't answered my first question. Do you expect to have English words by randomly picking alphabet letters and then comparing them with your list of English words?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to answer that. Yes. I would like see if any English words can be randomly typed by a random letter generator. But the whole problem is that I cant think of a way to do it so I am asking for help. Obviously I cant expect it to always give me word but there is always a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import string
import random

b = []
for i in range(100):
    a = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    b.append(a)
b = ''.join(b)

with open('engmix.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in f.readlines()]

output=[]    
for word in words:
    if word in b:
        output.append(word)
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ad', 'am', 'an', 'ape', 'au', 'b', 'bi', 'bim', 'c', 'cb', 'd', 'e',
 'ed', 'em', 'eo', 'f', 'fa', 'fy', 'g', 'gam', 'gem', 'go', 'gov', 'h', 
'i', 'j', 'k', 'kg', 'ko', 'l', 'le', 'lei', 'm', 'mg', 'ml', 'mr', 'n', 
'no', 'o', 'om', 'os', 'p', 'pe', 'pea', 'pew', 'q', 'ql', 'r', 's', 'si', 
't', 'ta', 'tap', 'tape', 'te', 'u', 'uht', 'uk', 'v', 'w', 'wan', 'x', 'y',
 'yo', 'yom', 'z', 'zed']
```

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on acquiring this result, assume your words are seperated by a single space:

```py
with open("allEnglishWords.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            print(word)
```

Also, you don't need `f.close()` inside a `with` block.

Comment: Your suggestion looked good so I tried to add it into my code, but I got an error regarding the f.split part of the code.
Error: 
`for word in f.split(" "):
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Sorry, I should check my code carefully, it should be `for word in line.split(" ")`, edited my answer

Comment: Just wondering where I can go from here. I was thinking of adding a simple if statement under the `for word in line.split(" "):` saying `if word in 'afcapdwa': print(word)` but then it outputs random stuff like `a c ca cap m  p  y ymca z` with cap being the only thing I want to be outputted but I get stuff like `m p y ymca z` that arn't even in the sting I provided.

Comment: `if word in 'afcapdwa'` means that you check if the word in these characters.  I think you need `if word in ['afcapdwa']`

Comment: The problem with this @Ballack is that it only checks if it is the exact word so if I type `if word in ['afcapdwa']: print(word)` it will output nothing but if I type `if word in ['cap']: print(word)` it will output cap

Comment: also if my previous comment was not specific enough here is an [example image](https://ibb.co/0q4X9yD)